# Where is the mistake in this Elliptic Curve code

Tags: haskell, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to write an implementation of elgamal with elliptic curves in haskell.
But there's some problem in my point addition function: as long as I keep adding the start point to itself I never reach the point at infinity (O).
Here is my code:

```
addP :: Curve->Point->Point->Point
addP _ O O = O
addP _ O p = p
addP _ p O = p
addP curve@(a,b,p) (P x1 y1) (P x2 y2) | x1 == x2 && y1 == -y2 = O
                                       | otherwise = P x3 ((m*(x1-x3)-y1) `mod''` p)
    where x3 = (((m*m)-x1-x2) `mod''` p)
          m | x1 /= x2 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
            | otherwise = (3*(x1*x1)+a)/(2*y1)
```

Where Curve is defined as

```
-- first double=a, second double=b, third double=p in y^2=x^3+ax+b mod p
type Curve = (Double, Double, Double)
```

and Point is defined as

```
data Point = P Double Double |
             P
             deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: what is extra `| P` doing there?

Answer (score 3):

> as long as I keep adding the start point to itself I never reach the point at infinity (O).

Could you please post the reference/link where you learned this. I have very limit knowledge of Elliptic curves but I know little bit of Haskell so I tried to see what is going with your code. Very first thing I noticed the use of division and double while you are using modular arithmetic modulo prime p. I am not able to see what you mod'' does so I changed your code little bit and it's working fine for me.

```
type Curve = ( Integer , Integer , Integer )
data Point = P Integer Integer | O
         deriving (Eq, Read, Show)


extendedGcd :: Integer -> Integer -> ( Integer , Integer )
extendedGcd a b
  | b == 0 = ( 1 , 0 )
  | otherwise = ( t , s - q * t ) where
      ( q , r ) = quotRem a b 
      ( s , t ) = extendedGcd b r


modInv :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
modInv  a b
  | gcd a b /= 1 = error " gcd is not 1 "
  | otherwise = d where
     d = until ( > 0 ) ( + b  ) . fst.extendedGcd a $ b


addP :: Curve->Point->Point->Point
addP _ O O = O 
addP _ O p = p 
addP _ p O = p 
addP ( a, b, p ) ( P x1 y1 ) ( P x2 y2 ) 
    | x1 == x2 && mod ( y1 + y2 ) p == 0 = O 
    | otherwise = P x3 ( mod ( m * ( x1 - x3 ) - y1 ) p ) where
            m | x1 /= x2 = ( mod ( y2 - y1 ) p ) * modInv ( mod ( x2 - x1 ) p ) p
              | otherwise = ( 3 * x1 * x1 + a ) * modInv  ( 2*y1 ) p
            x3 = mod ( m * m - x1 - x2 ) p
```

Lets take curve y^2 = x^3 + x + 1 modulo 13. Z_13 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]. Quadratic residue ( QR ) = [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12] and Quadratic non residue ( QNR )= [ 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11] of Z_13. Take x = 0 and we have y^2 = 1 ( mod 13 ) since 1 is in QR so solution for this equation is 1 and 12. We get two points ( 0, 1 ) and ( 0, 12 ). Putting x = 1, y^2 = 3 ( mod 13 ) so points corresponding to x = 1 is ( 1, 4 ) and ( 1, 9). Putting x=2, y^2 = 11 ( mod 13 ) and 11 is QNR so we don't have solution. Whenever a solution exists, it gives us two points and both are inverse of each other modulo prime p ( 13 in this case ). Total points on given curve is ( 0, 1 ), ( 0, 12 ), ( 1, 4 ), ( 1, 9 ), ( 4, 2 ), ( 4, 11 ), ( 5, 1 ), ( 5, 12 ), ( 7, 0 ), ( 7, 0 ), ( 8, 1 ), ( 8, 12 ), ( 10, 6 ), ( 10, 7 ), ( 11, 2 ), ( 11, 11 ). You can try all the points and see which one generate the whole group.

```
 *Main>take 20 . iterate ( addP ( 1 , 1 , 13 )  ( P 7 0 ) ) $ ( P 7 0  )
 [P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O,P 7 0,O]
 *Main> take 20 . iterate ( addP ( 1 , 1 , 13 )  ( P 0 12 ) ) $ ( P 0 12  )
 [P 0 12,P 10 6,P 7 0,P 10 7,P 0 1,O,P 0 12,P 10 6,P 7 0,P 10 7,P 0 1,O,P 0 12,P 10 6,P 7 0,P 10 7,P 0 1,O,P 0 12,P 10 6]
```

Coming back to Elgamal system
1. Bob chose elliptic curve E( a, b) over GF( p ) or GF ( 2^n ).
2. Bob chose a point on the curve e1( x1, y1 )
3. Bob chose an integer d.
4. Bob calculate e2(x2, y2 ) = d * e1( x1, y1 ).
5. Bob announce E( a, b, p ), e1( x1, y1 ) and e2( x2, y2) as your public key and keeps d as private key

Encryption. 
Alice selects P, point on the curve, as her plain text. She chose a random number r and computes C1 = r * e1, C2 = P + r * e2. 
Decryption.
Bob after receiving C1 and C2, computes C2 - d * C1 => P + r * e2 - d * r * e1 
=> P + r * d * e1 - d * r * e1 => P

Edit: You are correct! If you take generator element and keep adding it then you can generate the whole group. See the lecture by Christof Paar[1].
[1]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S9eZRHjP8g&list=PLn_QCKxjl9zmx3VojkDqljZcLCIslz7kB&index=37